# How to extract lines from two textfiles linked by heading number from the 1st 10 characters?

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

I have two files:

**file1.txt**:

```
0000001435 XYZ 与 ABC
0000001438warlaugh 世界
```

**file1.txt**:

```
0000001435 XYZ with abc
0000001436 DFC whatever
0000001437 FBFBBBF
0000001438 world of warlaugh
```

The lines in the separated file are linked by the number (1st 10 characters). The desired output is a tab separated file with lines that exists and `file1.txt` and the corresponding lines from `file2.txt`:

**file3.txt**:

```
XYZ 与 ABC   XYZ with abc
warlaugh 世界 world of warlaugh
```

**How do I get the corresponding lines and then create a tab separated file with lines that exists in `file1.txt` to produce `file3.txt`?**

**Note that only the first 10 character constitutes as the ID.**, there are cases like `0000001438warlaugh 世界` or even `0000001432231hahaha lol` and only the `0000001438` and `0000001432` is the ID.

I tried with python, **getfile3.py**:

```
import io
f1 = {line[:10]:line[10:].strip() for line in io.open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')}
f2 = {line[:10]:line[10:].strip() for line in io.open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')}

f3 = io.open('file3.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') 

for i in f1:
  f3.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(f1[i], f2[i]))
```

But is there a bash/awk/grep/perl command-line way that i can get `file3.txt`?

Comment: yes, that was the problem =( if not `cut` would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
{ key = substr($0,1,10); data = substr($0,11) }
NR==FNR { file1[key] = data; next }
key in file1 { print file1[key] data }
' file1 file2
```

You could use FIELDWIDTHS with GNU awk rather than substr() if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Super long Perl answer:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# add files here as needed
my @input_files = qw(file1.txt file2.txt);
my $output_file = 'output.txt';

# don't touch anything below this line
my @output_lines = parse_files(@input_files);

open (my $output_fh, ">", $output_file) or die;
foreach (@output_lines) {
    print $output_fh "$_\n";                    #print to output file
    print "$_\n";                               #print to console
}
close $output_fh;

sub parse_files {
    my @input_files = @_;                       #list of text files to read.
    my %data;                                   #will store $data{$index} = datum1 datum2 datum3

    foreach my $file (@input_files) {           
        open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die;       
        while (<$fh>) { 
            chomp;                              
            if (/^(\d{10})\s?(.*)$/) {
                my $index = $1;
                my $datum = $2;
                if (exists $data{$index}) {
                    $data{$index} .= "\t$datum";
                } else {
                    $data{$index} = $datum;
                } #/else
            } #/if regex found
        } #/while reading current file
        close $fh;
    } #/foreach file

    # Create output array
    my @output_lines;
    foreach my $key (sort keys %data) {
        push (@output_lines, "$data{$key}");
    } #/foreach

    return @output_lines;
} #/sub parse_files
```